# Por que ao somar dois valores com decimais o resultado não é exato?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando somar dois valores com decimais de duas variáveis:

```js
valor1 = 10.00;
valor2 = 10.99;
console.log(valor1+valor2);
```

Ao somar os dois valores é retornado `20.990000000000002` e não `20.99`.

Quando eu somo com os valores com decimais diferente de zero, o resultado é exato, por exemplo:

```js
valor1 = 10.03;
valor2 = 10.81;
console.log(valor1+valor2);
```

Por que o resultado do primeiro exemplo não é exato?

Comment: Comece por ler [essa resposta do jefferson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-os-tipos-float-double-e-decimal/219330#219330). Mas tentando resumir o máximo possível, alguns números não são representáveis em binário, tal como 0.1, ficando assim dizimas infinitas e não dando o resultado pretendido. [Leia também este artigo (em inglês)](http://floating-point-gui.de/). Tenho quase a certeza que esta pergunta é duplicada de outra, mas não achei

Comment: Para o caso geral, a resposta que o @Isac indicou é a mais indicada. Para o caso específico, seria necessário pegar a representação em mantissa de base binária para poder chegar a alguma conclusão. A propósito, toda soma com valores inteiros (ou terminados em `.00`) pequenos é exata em pontos flutuantes =] Os seus valores somados me fazem crer que o erro incidente da segunda seja a mais de 7 casas de distância, portanto o formatador considera insignificante para mostrar. Ou seja, creio que continua "não perfeita", mas que a imperfeição seja muito pequena

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Fui dar uma lida hoje sobre o assunto e consegui entender a questão do ponto flutuante. Realmente faz sentido.

Comment: @dvd particularmente não achei que nenhuma das respostas já dadas aqui foram boas. Acho que é o caso de você por o resultado da sua pesquisa (ou se for o caso, se as perguntas que abordam o assunto de ponto flutuante sejam em essência a mesma que a sua, marcar como duplicata)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Concordo contigo. Pelo que pesquisei, uma das respostas deu uma "beliscada" mas não fez uma abordagem mais aprofundada. Vou ver se formulo uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Se quiser responder tb, fique à vontade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque não existe uma forma de representar o 20.99 de maneira exata com um número de ponto flutuante. Não é só no javascript que tem esse efeito colateral, todas as linguagens que usam algum tipo de ponto flutuante sofrem do mesmo problema.

Você pode, nesse caso específico, usar o método [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para mostrar apenas as 2 casas desejadas:

```js
valor1 = 10.00;
valor2 = 10.99;
console.log((valor1+valor2).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Experimente usar o toFixed():

```
<script>
  var valor1 = 10.00;
  var valor2 = 10.99;
  var soma = ( valor1 + valor2 );
  console.log(soma.toFixed(2));
</script>
```

Referência:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

```js
var valor1 = 10.00;
var valor2 = 10.99;
var soma = ( valor1 + valor2 );
console.log(soma.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

Penso que seja melhor fazer arrendondamento, tofixed pode não dar o valor esperado.

```
function myRound(val, dec) {
    return (Math.round(val*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec)).toFixed(dec);
}

var valor1 = 10.00;
var valor2 = 10.99;
var soma = ( valor1 + valor2 );
soma = myRound(soma, 2);
```