# Problema com ponto flutuante Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ponto-flutuante

Estou [escrevendo um algoritmo](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098) onde incremento variáveis float em `0.2`, porém, depois de alguns incrementos ao invés de incrementar `2.2` para `2.4`, por exemplo, o programa incrementa para `2.4000000000000004`

Já li sobre esse "bug" do Python (eu sei que não é bug, mas não consegui encontrar uma palavra melhor), mas não consigo encontrar a referência para estudar uma solução. Segue o algoritmo:

```
J1, J2, J3, I = 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0

while I <= 2:
    print('I={} J={}'.format(I, J1))
    print('I={} J={}'.format(I, J2))
    print('I={} J={}'.format(I, J3))
    J1 += 0.2
    J2 += 0.2
    J3 += 0.2
    I += 0.2
```

E a saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se for só questão de exibição, você pode formatar a saída com `{:.2}`, limitando, assim, apenas duas casas decimais. Se for utilizar para operações matemáticas, utilize o módulo `decimal` como já respondido.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969

Comment: Nessa resposta eu exibo um exemplo de cálculo com uma classe de números que compartilha o mesmo problema dos números de ponto flutuante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272376/64969

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/273728/64969

Comment: Leia [Aritmética de ponto flutuante: problemas e limitações](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embora a resposta do @Pedro tenha sido de grande ajuda, encontrei a resposta com exemplos e tudo mais na SO em inglês. [Aqui está o link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473770/how-to-avoid-floating-point-errors)

Meu código, agora funcionando perfeitamente, ficou da seguinte maneira a quem interessar:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D

J1, J2, J3, I = D(1.0), D(2.0), D(3.0), D(0)

while I <= 2:
    print('I={} J={}'.format(I, J1))
    print('I={} J={}'.format(I, J2))
    print('I={} J={}'.format(I, J3))
    J1 += D("0.2")
    J2 += D("0.2")
    J3 += D("0.2")
    I += D("0.2")
```

Answer (score 9):

Não é um bug do Python, e sim um problema inerente de como computadores representam [ponto flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%ADrgula_flutuante).

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.3
0.4
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

Felizmente, o Python nos oferece um jeito simples de resolver o problema: o módulo `decimal`.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.2')
Decimal('0.3')
```

É importante notar que usando o `Decimal`, *devemos iniciar o número como uma string*. Senão, ele interpreta o argumento como ponto flutuante e temos o mesmo problema:

```
>>> Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.2)
Decimal('0.3000000000000000166533453694')
```

[Essa página](https://0.30000000000000004.com/) mostra a reação de diversas linguagens ao problema.

Comment: Outra sugestão é deixar o numero em questão em float mesmo, e cuidar do arreondamento só no momento de exibir o número (exibir = qualquer saída: tela, arquivo, HTML, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Como Pedro disse, não é um bug do Python.

Se você sabe que o incremento sempre será de `0.2` (ou cualquer número fixo), pode simplesmente guardar os valors multiplicados por `5` (o inverso multiplicativo do incremento) como integros e dividir por `5.0` quando precisa do valor como `float`. Isso evite problemas com sumar erros de arredondamento.

---

Como foi pedido, um exemplo simples:

```
J1, J2, J3, I = 5, 10, 15, 0

while I <= 10:
    print( 'I={} J={}'.format(I/5.0, J1/5.0) )
    print( 'I={} J={}'.format(I/5.0, J2/5.0) )
    print( 'I={} J={}'.format(I/5.0, J3/5.0) )
    J1 += 1
    J2 += 1
    J3 += 1
    I += 1
```

Com um resultado de:

```
I=0.0 J=1.0
I=0.0 J=2.0
I=0.0 J=3.0
I=0.2 J=1.2
I=0.2 J=2.2
I=0.2 J=3.2
I=0.4 J=1.4
I=0.4 J=2.4
I=0.4 J=3.4
I=0.6 J=1.6
I=0.6 J=2.6
I=0.6 J=3.6
I=0.8 J=1.8
I=0.8 J=2.8
I=0.8 J=3.8
I=1.0 J=2.0
I=1.0 J=3.0
I=1.0 J=4.0
I=1.2 J=2.2
I=1.2 J=3.2
I=1.2 J=4.2
I=1.4 J=2.4
I=1.4 J=3.4
I=1.4 J=4.4
I=1.6 J=2.6
I=1.6 J=3.6
I=1.6 J=4.6
I=1.8 J=2.8
I=1.8 J=3.8
I=1.8 J=4.8
I=2.0 J=3.0
I=2.0 J=4.0
I=2.0 J=5.0
```

Provavelmente seria melhor encapsular o código para fazer a multiplicação de divisão dentro de uma classe, mas não conheço Python tanto para dar um exemplo bom disso.

Tambem já ouvi falar de classes que guardem frações em vez de pontos flutuantes para guardar (quase) qualquer número racional sem perder precisão.

Eu acho que a classe `Decimal` do Python já faz uma coisa semelhante ao que eu estou descrevendo, mas quarda um número integro e guarda um poder de dez para fazer a divisão (ou multiplicação). Assim eu acho que `Decimal` é parecido com ponto flutuante, mas com poderes de dez em vez de poderes de dois.