# Valores quebrados muito longos não sendo reconhecidos dentro do If, em Python

Tags: python

Escrevi esse código abaixo que te pede um número entre 0 e 180. Ele está completamente protegido contra valores fora desse conjunto e contra letras. Eu gostaria de saber o por quê de, por exemplo, quando eu escrevo algum número quebrado tão, ou mais longo que 179.99999999999999, ele não reconhece.

```
while True:
    try:
        x = float(input('Digite um valor entre 0 e 180: '))
        if x <= 0 or x >= 180:
            print(' ')
            print('O número precisa estar entre 0 e 180.')
            continue
    except:
        print(' ')
        print('O valor precisa ser um número.')
        continue
    break
```

Comment: o `float` tende a arredondar números deste tipo. Pense em utilizar o `Decimal`. `from decimal import Decimal` e `angulo = Decimal(input('Digite um valor entre 0 e 180: '))`. Espero que ajude

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052

Comment: Essa pergunta e resposta vai dar uma ajuda tbm https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274772/problema-com-ponto-flutuante-python-3

Comment: E essa daqui dá uma explicação do problema e mostra a abordagem de diferentes linguagens ao tema https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Você precisa estudar a documentação da linguagem, problemas com ponto flutuante são comum em linguagens de programação. Claro que, se você tentar entender se de fato vai precisar de todas essas casas decimais, vale a profundar https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float e https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se, sua intenção for implementar um código que permita a inserção de apenas valores **numéricos**, do tipo **float** e que estejam no intervalo fechado **[0, 180]** você deve prestar atenção quanto à sua estrutura de decisão - **bloco if**. Neste caso, a forma correta de implementação do bloco if seria:

```
if (x < 0) or (x > 180):
```

Outra coisa, quando pretender capturar alguma **[exceção](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/errors.html)**, especifique qual é a que deseja capturar. Pois, não é uma boa prática de programação em Python 3.x, deixar de especificar o tipo de exceção desejado. Neste caso, a sua linha na qual especifica uma exceção deveria também exibir o tipo de exceção. Desta forma, a linha de código seria:

```
except ValueError:
```

Observe que este tipo de exceção retorna a exceção que foi provocada por erro de valor. Que, ao que parece, é a que mais se ajusta ao seu caso.

Se quiser ficar atento quanto a estilização do python acesse **[Este link](https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo)**.

Finalizando, o código melhorado e mais eficiente seria:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = float(input('Digite um valor entre "0" e "180": '))
        if (x < 0) or (x > 180):
            print('O número precisa estar entre "0" e "180"!')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('O valor precisa ser um número real! ')

print(x)
```

Outra coisa, se desejar pular uma linha em branco, na exibição dos seus prints, basta usar **"\n"** antes das frases que estiverem dentro de seus prints.

E, por último, respondendo à sua pergunta, se desejas entender um pouco como se comporta os arredondamentos em Python visite a **[Documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)**. Não pretendo entrar em detalhes técnicos pelo fato de não querer expandir muito o post.

Comment: Procurei na documentação e não achei onde diz que o Python arredonda floats para 15 casas decimais. Tem algum link que sustente essa afirmação?
Até onde sabia o motivo do "arredondamento" é o mencionado nos comentários da pergunta.