# Problema com calculo de porcentagem jquery

Tags: jquery, console, float, replace, porcentagem

Boa tarde ✌️✌, estou com problema com calculo de porcentagem, mas o erro no ocorre na casa do milhao pra cima, alguem tem ideia doque pode ser?

```
var cost_value = $('#cost_value').val().replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
var unitary_value = parseFloat(cost_value) + (parseFloat(cost_value) / 100 * 
50.00);
console.log(unitary_value);
console.log(number_format(unitary_value, 2, ',', '.'));
```

exenplo de saida

```
cost_value entrada:500000.00
unitary_value saida:750.000,00
cost_value entrada:5000.000.00
unitary_value saida:7.500,00
```

Comment: Provavelmente relacionado: [Realização de contas de ponto flutuante em JavaScript com precisão absoluta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14728/3774)

Comment: Provavelmente relacionado: [Por que ao somar dois valores com decimais o resultado não é exato?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/273728/3774)

Comment: Qual erro? Seria interessante **[edit]** a pergunta colocando alguns valores de exemplo, qual o resultado desejado e qual o resultado que obteve (e/ou a mensagem de erro, já que vc disse que ocorre um erro - mas não disse qual)

Comment: alterei de uma olhada na saida

Answer (score 3):

vamos por partes primeiro entenda o que cada função faz e o que ela retorna.

`.val()` do jQuery vai retornar o value do elemento que no caso será uma string,
segundo a documentação [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) o `string.replace("","")` (função JavaScript) ela substitui apenas o primeiro elemento encontrado na string, no seu caso quando entrar na casa do milhão ele possui 2 pontos [1.000.000,00].

Solução: o `string.replace("","")` aceita regex, use a seguinte `.replace(/\\./g,"")`

Comment: valeu salvou eu, não sabia que so retirava o primeiro, eu consegui com outra forma, mas nao queria gambiarra, vou ler mais a documentaçao apartir de agora.